# Return value of URL request

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, response, server, minecraft

I am writing a program based around Minecraft (I know it's easier in Java, that's the point), and one of my features includes entering one's username, and it will return whether that user is a premium member or not. This can be done manually in any web browser by going to:

https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=USERNAME

When USERNAME is replaced with an actual user name, for example:

https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=xTeCnOxShAdOwZz

then the webpage will just show 'true' or 'false', depending on whether that user is premium or not. In my case, it returns 'true', because I am a premium member. I would like to be able to return this as a boolean or string in visual basic, which I can then link to a label.

I really don't know where to start with the code, so all suggestions are welcome! Thank you! :)

Comment: Need more information. Web or winforms? How is the paid status determined? Where does the input come from, keyboard or URL? You say return true or false, but return from where and to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple. First you'll need a method to read a webpage into a string, here's a very basic one to do that:

```
Private Function GetWebPageText(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Return New StreamReader(Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
End Function
```

Then all you need to do is call the page with the username you want, and parse the return value into a boolean. You can do that easily with `Boolean.Parse(str)`, put it all together:

```
Private Function PlayerHasPremium(ByVal PlayerName As String) As Boolean
    Return Boolean.Parse(GetWebPageText("https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=" + PlayerName))
End Function
```

And you can then just call the method with the username to get the value as a boolean in your code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim TechnoShadowHasPremium As Boolean = PlayerHasPremium("xTeCnOxShAdOwZz")
    Dim MrLoreHasPremium As Boolean = PlayerHasPremium("MrLore")

    System.Console.WriteLine(TechnoShadowHasPremium) ' True
    System.Console.WriteLine(MrLoreHasPremium)       ' False
End Sub
```